# Unable to install locales and locales-all on docker image on Synology NAS

Tags: docker, ubuntu, synology

I'm trying to install Ubuntu as a docker container on a Synology rs1221+ NAS.

When I try to build the container with the command:

`docker build -t appy:1 .`

it ends with the following errors:

`E: Package 'locales' has no installation candidate E: Package 'locales-all' has no installation`

If I try it on my mac, everything works just fine.

I use the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt update
RUN apt install locales locales-all -y
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
RUN update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ENV TZ=Europe/Zurich
RUN ln -snf /us/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
RUN apt install tzdata -y
RUN apt install openssh-server sudo bash-completion tree git -y
RUN useradd -m -d /home/app -s /bin/bash -G sudo app
RUN echo 'app:pass1234' | chpasswd
RUN service ssh start

EXPOSE 22

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

Terminal output:

```
myName@rs1221: /volume1/docker/Ubuntu$ sudo docker build -t appy:1 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.56kB
Step 1/14: FROM ubuntu: 20.04
20.04: Pulling from library/ubuntu
Digest: sha256:33a5cc25d22c45900796a1aca487ad7a7cb09f09ea00b779e3b2026b4fc2fab
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu: 20.04
---> 6d894023726
Step 2/14: RUN apt update
---> Using cache
---> 7d3053e01bb9
Step 3/14: RUN apt install locales locales-all -y
---> Running in 5e5eded1fb3c
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Package locales is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
Package locales-all is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
E: Package 'locales' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'locales-all' has no
installation candidate
The command '/bin/sh -c apt install locales locales-all -y' returned a non-zer o code:100
```

Can you help me with this?

Comment: I tried the same installation on a Synology NAS rs2423RP+ and everything worked. Its in a different network but I don't think it has something to do with the firewall or other network stuff, since it's a very similar setup.
There is of course a difference in CPU. As i read in the following blog, some NAS models are not recommended for docker because they do not have AVX support.
Could this be the problem in my case?

https://mariushosting.com/synology-best-nas-for-docker/